# is there a way to fix list widget eror

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
class ProgressHUD extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool inAsyncCall;
  final double opacity;
  final Color color;
  final Animation<Color> valueColor;

  ProgressHUD({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.inAsyncCall,
    this.color = Colors.grey,
    this.opacity = 0.3,
    this.valueColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>();
    widgetList.add(child);
    if (inAsyncCall) {
      final modal = new Stack(
        children: [
          new Opacity(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: ModalBarrier(
              dismissible: false,
              color: color,
            ),
          ),
          new Center(
            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ],
      );
      widgetList.add(modal);
    }
    return Stack(
      children: [],
    );
  }
}
```

I did this but it keeps showing this error:

'List' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use a list literal, [], or the List.filled constructor instead.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

Comment: Seems like you should declare an empty list like so:  List<Widget> widgetList = [];

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line that is giving you the error:

```dart
List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>();
```

With the suggested constructor

```dart
 List<Widget> widgetList = <Widget>[];
```

Another option is to initialize it as an empty list:

```dart
List<Widget> widgetList = List<Widget>.empty(growable: true);
```

The [List docs](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html) have details on multiple constructors.